# Can you return json in golang http.Error?

Tags: go

Can you return json when `http.Error` is called?

```
        myObj := MyObj{
            MyVar: myVar}

        data, err := json.Marshal(myObj)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return 
        }
        w.Write(data)
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

        http.Error(w, "some error happened", http.StatusInternalServerError)
```

I see that it returns `200` with no `json` but the json is embed in `text`

Comment: The call to `w.Write(data)` writes the response header. The content type header set by `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")` is ignored because the response header was already written to the network.  The headers and response code set by `http.Error` are also ignored.

Answer (score 21):

I've discovered that it's really easy to read the Go source. If you click on the function in the docs, you will be taken to the source for the `Error` function: https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=61907:61959#L2006

```
// Error replies to the request with the specified error message and HTTP code.
// It does not otherwise end the request; the caller should ensure no further
// writes are done to w.
// The error message should be plain text.
func Error(w ResponseWriter, error string, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    fmt.Fprintln(w, error)
}
```

So if you want to return JSON, it's easy enough to write your own Error function.

```
func JSONError(w http.ResponseWriter, err interface{}, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(err)
}
```

Comment: I've just been checking on that, and I agree: there's no 'obligation' to return `text/plain` - OP can just implement her/his own Error func that returns json. I've added an example function to the answer.

Comment: That's what I meant ;) I wondered if errors _had to be_ text/plain, and they don't, as you said :)

Answer (score 5):

It should be plain text only.

[From docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Error)

> func Error(w ResponseWriter, error string, code int)
>
> Error replies to the request with the specified error message and HTTP
>   code. It does not otherwise end the request; the caller should ensure
>   no further writes are done to w. The error message should be plain
>   text.

Also I think your usage of `http.Error` is not correct. When you call `w.Write(data)`, the response is sent and response body will be closed. That is why you are getting 200 status instead of 500 from `http.Error`.

Instead of using `http.Error`, you can send your own error response with json just like how you would send any other response by setting the status code to an error code.

Answer (score 1):

Like @ShashankV said, you are writing the response in a wrong way.
As an example, the following is what I did during learning about writing RESTful API serving in Golang:

```golang
type Response struct {
    StatusCode int
    Msg string
}

func respond(w http.ResponseWriter, r Response) {
    // if r.StatusCode == http.StatusUnauthorized {
    //     w.Header().Add("WWW-Authenticate", `Basic realm="Authorization Required"`)
    // }

    data, err := json.Marshal(r)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        fmt.Fprintf(w, err.Error())
        return 
    }

    w.WriteHeader(r.StatusCode)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, r.Msg)
}

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    resp := Response{http.StatusOK, welcome}
    respond(w, resp)
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/shudipta/Book-Server/blob/master/book_server/book_server.go

Hope, this will help.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a bit late and there are some good answers already. Here are my 2 cents.

If you want to return JSON in case of error there are multiple ways to do so. I can list two:

1. Write your own Error handler method
2. Use the `go-boom` library

#### 1. Writing your own error handler method

One way is what @craigmj has suggested, i.e. create your own method, for eg.:

```golang
func JSONError(w http.ResponseWriter, err interface{}, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(err)
}
```

#### 2. Use the `go-boom` library

Another approach is using the [go-boom](https://github.com/darahayes/go-boom) library. For eg., in case the err relates to resource not found, you can do:

```golang
err := errors.New("User doesn't exist")
...
boom.NotFound(w, err)
```

And the response will be:

```js
{
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": ",
  "statusCode": 404
}
```

For more check the documentation of the `go-boom`.
Hope that helps.